# How do I send a file using a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.io

This is currently my bot.js

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == ';') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        console.info(cmd);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'killerbean':
            //    bot.sendFile({
             //       to: channelID,
            //      files: ['./emojis/killerbean.png']
             //   });
             logger.info(bot.channels);
             User.sendFile('./emojis/killerbean.png');
             //bot.channels[0].send('', new Discord.Attachment( './emojis/killerbean.png'));

            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
     }
});
```

The commented code is some stuff that I tried that hasn't worked. bot.sendFile is apparently not a method. I'm currently looking at using User.send, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

*How do I go about sending an image when someone types in the command ';killerbean'*

*Edit: Throwing in the package.json in case the dependencies or anything else there matters*

```
    {
      "name": "emoji-bot",
      "version": "1.0",
      "description": "Emojis+",
      "main": "bot.js",
      "author": "Joshua",
      "dependencies": {
        "discord-irc": "^2.5.1",
        "discord.io": "github:woor/discord.io#gateway_v6",
        "winston": "^2.4.0"
      }

    }
```

The emoji-bot user is also called emoji-bot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you should change two things:

1. Send attachments via a `channel` instance, if you want the image to show up in the same channel where the command `;killerbean` was sent. You can get the `channel` from the sent message using [`message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel).
2. Use [`.send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) instead of `.sendFile`. In the docs you can see that `.sendFile` is deprecated.

Here's how to send the image in the same channel where the command was sent (don't send an empty string `''` in the first parameter):

```
message.channel.send(new Discord.Attachment('./emojis/killerbean.png', 'killerbean.png') )
.catch(console.error);
```

Also, your `bot.on('message'...` listener should only have one parameter - `message` (as seen in the [example usage](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) in the docs). I would be surprised if you don't run into errors with your many parameters (`user`, `userID`, `channelID`, `message`, `evt`).

So your final command should look something like this:

```
// ...
bot.on('message', function (message) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == ';') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);

        switch(cmd) {

            case 'killerbean':
                message.channel.send(new Discord.Attachment('./emojis/killerbean.png', 'killerbean.png') )
                .then(msg => {
                    // do something after message sends, if you want
                })
                .catch(console.error);
                break;
         }
     }
});
```

**Edit:** The `discord.io` tag had not been added to the question when I added this answer. Now I know the old syntax was allowed, but the syntax in my answer works for basic `discord.js` code.

Comment: This helped a lot! However important to note is that I was using methods from and reading documentation for two separate things: discord.io and discord.js. I settled on discord.js as that was the documentation you provided and worked with your answer.

Comment: @Moralous - that is very good to know! I recently saw `discord.io` but haven't worked with it much, and didn't connect it to your syntax, so I just created a tag for `discord.io` so hopefully this doesn't confuse anyone else in the future.

Answer (score -1):

bot.sendFile({
   to: channelID,
   file: "killerbean.png"
})